# Where should I place uploads dir in Nuxt.js project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I had my uploads directory in a root, but to reach images inside the directory I had an api created.

Now the same but better solution would be to have this directory in a `static/` so I could reach the images throught the link easily.

Another option would be placing it inside `assets/` dirrectory and `require()` the image.

Which one is recommended and would be best solution?